# Get name of an object that is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to get variable name of an object which is empty. How can i get this?

My code

```
var array = [foo, bar, baz]
array.map((el)=>{
 if(Object.keys(el).length === 0) {
  //give me name of var from an array which is empty
 }
})
```

Comment: That's not possible. Why do you need it?

Comment: one of the objects might be empty due to misconfiguration. Must know which one for logs purpose.

Comment: Can you change `array`? Or anything else of that code? Is the order important?

Comment: Yes, I can change anything. Inserting values to an array and map over it was my first idea. Order is not important.

Comment: Maybe in each object of the array you can add an attribute _name, for example for a "foo" object you initialize it like var foo = { _name: "foo"} and in the code you shown above you check Object.keys(el).length === 1 and not 0 anymore, so if the condition is true you display el._name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get to a *variable name* from some arbitrary value. But you can supply *meta* information yourself. For example:

```js
const foo = {a: 42};
const bar = {};
const baz = {b: 451};

// Use an object, instead of an array. With the following syntax
// the variable *creates* a property of the same name.
const configs = {foo, bar, baz};

// find *empty* elements:
const emptyConfigs = Object.entries(configs).reduce((acc, [k, cfg]) => {
  return Object.keys(cfg).length === 0
    ? [...acc, k]
    : acc;
}, []);

console.log(emptyConfigs);
```

Ref: [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015)

---

Alternatively include the information with each array entry. Which has the added benefit that the configs can/could be inlined (and thus don't have a name).  E.g.:

```js
const foo = {a: 42};
const bar = {};
const baz = {b: 451};

const configs = [
  {key: 'foo', cfg: foo},
  {key: 'bar', cfg: bar},
  {key: 'baz', cfg: baz},
  {key: 'unnamed', cfg: {}}, // inlined config
];

const emptyConfigs = configs.reduce((acc, {key, cfg}) => {
  return Object.keys(cfg).length === 0
    ? [...acc, key]
    : acc;
}, []);

console.log(emptyConfigs);
```